# How do I run every possible pairwise comparison using the Wilcoxon Sign-Rank Test when there are more than two levels of a grouping variable?

Tags: r, loops, statistics, pairwise, pairwise.wilcox.test

I have a within-subjects dataset for which I am running pairwise comparisons on a dependent variable that is be separated into four groups.  I have the data organized long-ways and wide-ways:

Example long-ways:

| direction | count |
| --- | --- |
| l2l | 44 |
| l2l | 49 |
| r2r | 100 |
| r2r | 582 |
| r2l | 24 |
| r2l | 1000 |
| l2r | 3 |
| l2r | 244 |

Example wide-ways:

| l2l_count | r2r_count | r2l_count | l2r_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 44 | 100 | 24 | 3 |
| 49 | 582 | 1000 | 244 |

I am interested in looking at every possible pairwise comparison on the variable "count" based on the grouping variable "direction" in R.  However, I cannot figure out how to do this in R in an automated fashion.

With a data.frame called hcp_dir, I have tried using the following with my long-ways data:

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(hcp_dir$count, hcp_dir$direction, paired = TRUE, p.adj="bonf")
```

[image]

However, this only gives me a matrix of corrected p-values for every possible comparison, and does not yield a test statistic, which I need.

I have also tried using the following, which gives me bootstrapped confidence intervals, and an effect size, but no test statistic with long-ways oriented data:

```
wilcox_effsize(hcp_dir, count~direction, paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided", mu = 0, ci = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95, ci.type = "perc", nboot = 10000)
```

[image]

The only way I can figure out how to get a test statistic for the Wilcoxon sign-rank test is to use the following code, which requires the data to be organized wide-ways.  It is ultimately with this script that I cannot figure out how to iterate through every possible direction pairing automatically.

```
wilcox.test(hcp_dir$l2l_count, hcp_dir$r2r_count, paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided")
```

[image]

Note that this is the only way I am able to get a V statistic.  I need to figure out how to iterate across all possible comparisons for efficiency.

Comment: Chisquare tests are more suitable for count data. Wilcoxon tests are designed for continuous data. After doing a `chisq.test` on the entire table you can also do tests on sub-tables.

Comment: @IRTFM Thank you so much for your response. While I understand chi2 is appropriate for count data, the data in question is comparing different numbers of streamlines derived from diffusion weighted imaging tract reconstructions, which are often treated as “pseudo-continuous”. I am trying to understand macro-structural differences relating to intra-individual anatomy across a multitude of different factors. However, I want to do so in a focused manner.

Comment: Try `rstatix::pairwise_wilcox_test(df, count ~ direction)`

Comment: @NicChr You are a life saver!  What a simple fix; this worked beautifully!